# Можно ли средствами java, не загружая файл в память перезаписать строку?

Tags: java

Есть очень большой текстовый файл содержащий список. Количество строк — миллиард и больше. Если загружать его в память как массив байтов, типа `Files.readAllBytes()` и перебирать, может возникнуть ошибка `OutOfMemoryError`. Другие методы будут работать медленно.. Нашёл интересное решение для чтения с заданной строки.

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tail -"+nLines+" "+file);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

Можно ли таким же образом перезаписать или удалить строку в файле?

Comment: не загружайте файл целиком. Грузите частями и записывайте частями

Comment: @ArchDemon Как вариант. Но, если я знаю номер строки, может как-то можно удалить эту строку? Перезаписывать каждый раз файл - это ресурсоемко.

Comment: А  можно  использовать  ByteBuffer из пакета java.nio. Удобно  когла  неадо  что  то  разместить  за  пределами  jvm

Comment: Вы хотите перезаписать строку средствами Java, а в примере пользуетесь средствами операционной системы. Команда [`tail`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tail&category=1) это утилита операционной системы. Если вам это не принципиально, то вы можете писать в середину файла [с помощью команды `dd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17203140), но там все те же ограничения, которые я описал в своем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1448304): вы не можете отсчитать номер строки и не можете изменить размер файла.

Comment: @Vadik вы дали хороший ответ, но мне не нравится условие "знать длину каждой строки") Я думаю если с помощью `Runtime` мы можем задать начало строки для чтения, то проделав небольшие манипуляции с `indexOf` или добавив `getFilePointer()` можно узнать offset. Но это лишь моя теория... Надо пробовать.

Answer (score 2):

Файл, который хранится на диске, это последовательность байт. Вы не можете знать сколько в нем переносов строк и где они расположены, пока не считаете этот файл, начиная с первого байта.

Возможно, ваша проблема может быть решена с помощью [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), но вы должны знать на какое количество байт вам нужно сместиться от начала файла, чтобы писать сразу в середину файла. Вы также не сможете удалять текст из середины, так как это бы означало, что вам нужно перезаписать оставшуюся половину файла. Но вы можете имитировать удаление заменой символов на пробелы.

Допустим, у вас есть файл `input.txt` в кодировке ASCII со следующим содержимым:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

Зная длину каждой строки, мы можем перезаписать третью строку на другое значение:

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
int lineLength = 4; // длина каждой строки
int lineNumber = 3; // номер строки для записи
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    raf.seek((lineLength + 1) * (lineNumber - 1));
    raf.writeBytes("IJKL");
}
```

Во всех остальных случаях, я думаю, нужно использовать BufferedReader/BufferedWriter, чтобы посчитать количество строк и вставить или удалить из середины файла произвольное количество текста.

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже это то, что нужно. Надо проверить...